# Apache Poi RowIterator only returning the last 100 (0 - 99) rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have code where a workbook is created by one process and then read by another without writing the workbook to a file (the second process actually writes the file to a csv file).

When the book is read only the last 100 rows are read.  What do I need to do to get the iterator to return all of the rows?  The example code is shown below and the complete example is here:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/poi-example-01

**Code:**

```
package org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Test;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class IteratorExampleIntegrationTest {

    public static final int MAX = 220;
    
    @Test
    public void shouldWriteCells() throws Exception {
        SXSSFWorkbook book = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("sheet-001");
        // create the book
        log.info("* * * CREATING * * *");
        for(int r=0;r<MAX;r++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
            for(int c=0;c<5;c++) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
                String str = "ROW " + r + " COL " + c;
                log.info("CREATING: " + str);
                cell.setCellValue(str);
            }
        }
        log.info("* * * ECHO * * *");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            log.info("Got Row: " + row.getRowNum());
        }
        book.close();
        log.info("Done.");
    }

}
```

**Output**
(truncated at "..." for brevity)

```
19:55:59.366 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - * * * CREATING * * *
19:55:59.378 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 0 COL 0
19:55:59.379 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 0 COL 1
19:55:59.380 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 0 COL 2
19:55:59.380 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 0 COL 3
19:55:59.380 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 0 COL 4
...
...
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 219 COL 1
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 219 COL 2
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 219 COL 3
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - CREATING: ROW 219 COL 4
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - * * * ECHO * * *
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 120
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 121
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 122
19:55:59.448 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 123
...
...
19:55:59.452 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 217
19:55:59.452 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 218
19:55:59.452 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Got Row: 219
19:55:59.595 [main] INFO org.nachc.examples.poi.iteratorexample.IteratorExampleIntegrationTest - Done.
```

--- EDIT ------------------

For clarity: the solution here was not to get all the rows back from the streaming row iterator but to implement a streaming process that could be in-lined with the use of the streaming row iterator (see comments in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get the iterator to return all of the rows?

Don't use `SXSSFWorkbook`, because that's the **streaming** version, which only keeps the last 100 rows (configurable) in memory before flushing them to disk, hence the streaming part.

So says the **documentation**:

> [***POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF/SXSSF - Java API To Access Microsoft Excel Format Files***](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/#SXSSF+(Since+POI+3.8+beta3))
>
> Due to the streaming nature of the implementation, there are the following limitations when compared to XSSF:
>
> - **Only a limited number of rows are accessible** at a point in time.

---

> [***Javadoc of `SXSSFWorkbook`***](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html)
>
> Streaming version of `XSSFWorkbook` implementing the "BigGridDemo" strategy. This allows to write very large files without running out of memory as **only a configurable portion of the rows are kept in memory** at any one time.

---

> [***SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API)***](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)
>
> SXSSF (package: `org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming`) is an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF to be used when very large spreadsheets have to be produced, and heap space is limited. SXSSF achieves its low memory footprint by **limiting access to the rows that are within a sliding window**, while XSSF gives access to all rows in the document. Older rows that are no longer in the window **become inaccessible**, as they are written to the disk.
>
> You can specify the window size at workbook construction time via `new SXSSFWorkbook(int windowSize)` or you can set it per-sheet via `SXSSFSheet#setRandomAccessWindowSize(int windowSize)`
>
> When a new row is created via `createRow()` and the total number of unflushed records would exceed the specified window size, then the row with the lowest index value is **flushed and cannot be accessed** via `getRow()` anymore.
>
> The **default window size is 100** and defined by `SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE`.

Comment: I'm using SXSSFWorkbook as I will need to support very large files.  It sounds like the only way I might be able to support large files (streaming with SXSSFWorkbook) and be able to get the data I need would be to save the workbook to disc and then read the saved file.  Is there another way to "reset" (i.e. go back and start with the first 100 records) the streaming version (the data must be saved somewhere as the data can eventually be written to disc using a save workbook operation).

Comment: @John Close the sheet to flush the last rows (`sheet.close()`), then get the sheet again (`book.getSheet("sheet-001")`).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, gave it a try but it looks like SXSSFSheet doesn't have a close method (I'm at 4.1.2).  Workbook has a close but it didn't do the trick.  Thanks for the help.  (setting the window size did work, gets me through the day but I don't love that if I want to process a very large file I'll have to set a very large window size... I feel like this will somewhat defeat the efficiency of the streaming version).

Comment: @John Since you work with very large spreadsheets, you want streamed processing, so you need to ask yourself why you need to read the rows after just creating them. E.g. are you reading them to sum some numeric column? If so, why can't you do that in the same loop where you create the rows? Re-think what you're doing.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. Original design was separation of concerns: processing the file is separate from writing the file to csv (i.e. I have a csv file writer that can be used anywhere we have a workbook we want to write to csv (writeToCsv(Workbook book) method).  I don't want to break that separation of concerns but I think I somewhat have my cake and eat it to here:  Write a reusable streaming csv writer that can be called line by line by the processes using streaming implementation of poi with methods like open(File file), writeLine(Row row), and close().  Thanks!